# E2E Testing for AngularJS App on another computer

Tags: testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm developing single page application on *AngularJS* for learning. My project is located on *Apache HTTP Server* on another computer, I use *WinSCP* synchronisation while developing so that it is always the last version of my work.

Halfway through (actually, when I has already finished the biggest part the application), I realized that I don't have any tests and I should learn how to test what I do not just manually. I decided to try writing *E2E* tests for my *AngularJS* application using *Karma Test Runner*.

I installed *Karma* via `npm`, initialized it (`karma init test/karma.conf.js`), but what happens now?
I tried `karma start test/karma.conf.js` it launches Chrome (as I stated in config) and says that

> Karma - connected
>   Chrome 26.0 (Windows) is idle

even though in conf file there are specified my test file:

```
files = [
  'test/first_test.js'
];
```

And that's what inside it:

```
describe('my app', function() {
  browser().navigateTo('/');

  it('should then be.', function() {
    expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/login');
  });

});
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I realized, it's not just 'Chrome is idle', there's also console log error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined

Any ideas? I'm so confused right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, looks like I solved it myself.

I should have added

```
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
```

to the files property of karma config file. After that, I progressed a little bit, but still got a lot of troubles, but essentially the main was that I got error that `resumeBootstrap` was undefined. My app was using *AngularJS* 1.0.4, but it looks like Karma's Adapters are for 1.0.6+ only. Upgrading app to 1.0.6 helped with `resumeBootstrap`.

Regarding testing the app on external server:

```
proxies = {
 '/': 'http://another.internal/app/'
};
```

and don't forget to change links to CSS and JS files in app's index.html from local (`css/style.css`) to web (`//another.internal/app/css/style.css`).

Answer (score 1):

Browser is only defined inside of beforeEach. Try this:

```
describe('my app', function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser().navigateTo('/');
    });

    it('should then be.', function() {
        expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/login');
    });

});
```

Comment: Now it keeps saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined` 
 
Chrome 26.0 (Windows) ERROR  
 Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined at long-long-path  
Chrome 26.0 (Windows): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.124 secs / 0 secs)

Comment: Thanks, that helped with `browser is not defined`, but there still were errors around and my biggest mistake was not adding `ANGULAR_SCENARIO` and `ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER` to files property in options of Karma. If you are interested what was wrong more, look below, I answered it myself.